# What is difference between dataframe created using SparkR and dataframe created using Sparklyr?

Tags: r, parquet, databricks, sparkr, sparklyr

I am reading a parquet file in Azure databricks:
Using SparkR > read.parquet()
Using Sparklyr > spark_read_parquet()
Both the dataframes are different, Is there any way to convert SparkR dataframe into the sparklyr dataframe and vice-versa ?

Comment: A Spark dataframe should be a Spark dataframe, regardless of the API that created it. (Different APIs may offer different transformation methods for it though.) Can you elaborate what differences you see exactly?

Comment: I am not able to use the sparklyr commands for data manipulation on a dataframe created using the read.parquet() (which is a SparkR command).

Comment: Well that is to be expected, since the R objects that represent the dataframes are different for the two packages even if the spark dataframe is the same. Additionally the dataframes may belong to different spark contexts depending on your configuration. Why don't you just directly read the parquet file with sparklyr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sparklyr creates tbl_spark. This is essentially just a lazy query written in Spark SQL. SparkR creates a SparkDataFrame which is more of a collection of data that is organized using a plan.

In the same way you can't use a tbl as a normal data.frame you can't use a tbl_spark the same way as a SparkDataFrame.

The only way I can think of to convert one to the other would be to write it to your data lake/ data warehouse or read it into r first.

Comment: Seems a good solution, but I want to use the credential passthrough so reading the data again is the main problem. Sparklyr doesn't support credential passthrough.