# StringInderxer and One hot encoding in SparkR

Tags: azure-databricks, sparkr, sparklyr

I am trying to convert string variable in SparkR to numeric by using one hot encoding concept and using stringindexer on below code:
df<-ft_string_indexer(spark_df,input_col=cluster_group,output_col=new)
However, I am getting below error:
no applicable method for 'ft_string_indexer' applied to an object of class "SparkDataFrame"

Any idea on correct code for stringindexer and Onehotencoding in SparkR?

Answer (score 1):

First, ft_string_indexer() is for sparklyr not sparkR. For differences between the two see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63464517/what-is-difference-between-dataframe-created-using-sparkr-and-dataframe-created/63512237#63512237). In general, sparklyr is better for ML so I'd recommend moving to sparklyr if you can.

Second, it is worth noting that SparkR uses onehotencoder in the background for all of its ML. This is noted [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/sparkr/overview.html#). So, you maybe able to get away without doing it depending on what your model.

I couldn't find a SparkR function that does the same thing as ft_string_indexer() exactly, but you could use encode. This should hold up in whatever ML you're doing but without an example I can't be sure. The following is taken from the SparkR [documentation on encode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/index.html):

```
df <- createDataFrame(as.data.frame(Titanic, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
tmp <- mutate(df, s1 = encode(df$Class, "UTF-8"))
tmp2 <- mutate(tmp, s2 = base64(tmp$s1), 
                    s3 = decode(tmp$s1, "UTF-8"),
                    s4 = soundex(tmp$Sex))
```